# Store timer in a SQLite database - python

Tags: python, mysql, database, sqlite

So I'm using a Python + SQLite  for my project and I have a question, is it possible to do something like this:

There are `FirstName, LastName, Timer` in my database

```
create_table(FirstName, LastName, Timer)
data_entry(John, Doe, 1 hour)

print_data() #that function should print me John Doe in 1 hour
```

So the question is can you store timer in your database which should be automatically changed at least every 1 hour. So you don't have to change data manually.

Hope my question is clear enough

Comment: Hi: Its possible (using various frameworks) to run scheduled tasks, and some databases do have internal scheduled work. However I don't believe this is possible in SQLLite *just* in the database.

Comment: Ok, there are some pretty big design flaws in your application and you need to provide additional information: How do you run this python code? From a console? Where and how do you want to display output? Please state what you want to achieve. It sound like you want to write some kind of service that periodically updates your database.

Comment: You can't do it only with your SQLite, guess you need to use [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: If he wants to create a service with python, there is no need for cron, he can just use python for this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for sqlite alone is definitely not- there's no engine running in the background where sqlite is concerned, it's just a single file on your disk.

I would look at cron jobs to do the update. They can run a script periodically